# Bluetooth mouse doesn't pair after i forget it

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

i have a ROG Pugio II mouse. after a firmware update, it's Bluetooth connection became laggy so i forgot it, now i can't connect it again. it is visible in Bluetooth setting, when i click connect, it takes a while and then it say try again. I tried updating Bluetooth driver, removing and installing Bluetooth driver but it doesn't connect. mouse is OK, it works on other devices. bluetooth is ok too, my jbl BT headphone works good. my laptop is Zephyrus G15 and Wifi card is realtek 8821CE. thanks in advance.

Comment: Try updating your Bluetooth driver and then restart the machine - test.

Comment: i updated driver, reinstall it and it's about 15 days that i'm trying to fix it. so many restarts and updates..